# Virtual Assistants: A drain on the community?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed a recent glut of so called "Virtual Assistants" asking for help within a few different Google Sheets / Excel related tags on StackOverflow.

I'm fine to help such folks if it's just help, but lately it feels more and more that they are trying to farm out their work to volunteers.

What is the best way to handle this problem/suspicion? I'm relatively new to the Stack Community so maybe this is a commonly discussed problem and someone could point me to a discussion thread?

Comment: Is the question and the answer useful for future visitors? Does the question stand on its own (IOW you don't need to have access to the Google sheet / Excel)? is the question unique (aka not a duplicate of a beaten to death problem).  If yes, then the content is welcome/useful, answer/vote accordingly. If no, close vote as unclear / too broad  or a custom reason, downvote the question.

Comment: Because it's not possible to accurately and fairly detect what someone does for a living and/or whether or not they're just outsourcing work on purpose, all we can do is act on what is posted.

Comment: Questions that show no effort are already likely to be downvoted, if not closed (for also being too broad, unclear, or lacking debugging details) so I don’t think we need to do anything special if the user happens to be a virtual assistant. I’ve never seen a question where the user said they were a VA but there’s plenty of [meta discussion on how to handle questions from students](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Students) that’s applicable.

Comment: What is a *"Virtual Assistant"*?

Comment: @bad_coder - seems like those "work from home, performing tasks that an administrative assistant or secretary would normally do" and not AIs yet :) And in this context, I presume, the same as help vampires

Comment: But .. is it also a _virtual_ drain? (I'm sorry, I am so sorry, I just couldn't resist)

Comment: I really wanted to believe that we had a sudden slew of questions on the network written by Siri and Alexa.

Comment: Nearly two years after this question was asked, I have no idea what it even referred to.